# Send every 5 observations to the next row in r

Tags: r, text-mining

I am new to R and I have a problem with my dataset. I created a data frame and all my data are in 1 row and I need to send every 5 observations to the next row:

```
My current dataset called ndf: 

  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4 ... Col_4005 
1 text1  text2  text3  text4     text4005 

What I need: 

    Col_1     Col_2     Col_3     Col_4     Col_5 
1   text1     text2     text3     text4     text5 
2   text6     text7     text8     text9     text10 
...
801 text4001  text4002  text4003  text4004  text4005
```

How can I do that?

I tried to use a loop but it didn't work. I also used this function that didn't work:

```
ndf<-ndf[rep(seq_len(ncol(ndf)), each = 5), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matrix`:

```
matrix(ndf, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
#[1,] "text1"  "text2"  "text3"  "text4"  "text5" 
#[2,] "text6"  "text7"  "text8"  "text9"  "text10"
#[3,] "text11" "text12" "text13" "text14" "text15"
#[4,] "text16" "text17" "text18" "text19" "text20"
```

Data:

```
ndf <- data.frame(t(paste0("text", 1:20)))
```